# How to fix the recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

It's a simple question of recursive function, which extracting every digits from a positive number. As the comment mentioned, I have known the mistake is because of global variable, but I still have no idea to fix it to get expected result. Thanks.

```py
def getdigits(n):
    if n == 0:    
        return list_1[::-1]
    list_1.append(n % 10)
    return getdigits(int(n / 10))



list_1 = []

print(getdigits(120)) # output = [1,2,0]
print(getdigits(5)) # output = [5,1,2,0]
```

But the expected output should be

```py
print(getdigits(120)) # expected output = [1,2,0]
print(getdigits(5)) # expected output = [5]
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with recursion - `list_1` is global.

Comment: init list_1 again before second call

Comment: appending to existing List

Comment: But if put list_1 in the function, the function does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the existing **LIST** that already have values from the previous function call.

First clear the list and then try to call for another value.\

Try it

```
def getdigits(n):
    if n == 0:    
        return list_1[::-1]
    list_1.append(n % 10)
    return getdigits(int(n / 10))



list_1 = []
print(getdigits(120))
list_1.clear() #clear list values
print(getdigits(5))
```

Comment: Yes, it does work, thanks a lot. However, can I get a better function without bug like this?

Comment: Better in what terms... Its working fine just use loop if you want to take user input multiple times

Comment: Yeh...it is a bit tricky maybe. I just want to write a recursive function and store the digits using list. As you say, there are another easier to do this like using a stack in function. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getdigits(n):
    global list_1
    if n == 0:

        listTemp = list_1

        list_1 = []

        return listTemp

    list_1.append(n % 10)
    return getdigits(int(n / 10))



list_1 = []

print(getdigits(120)) # output = [1,2,0]
print(getdigits(5)) # output = [5]
```

you need to declare list 1 as a global varible inside your function so you can clear list one within th function

i have tested it and got that output

Comment: Ummm..yes, it does work for the second output but the first output is fault now. In addition, the code does not look beautiful haha. Thanks anyway.